# AWS token expired while downloading file from S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to download a file from my S3 bucket using AWS SDK for Android. Here is the code I'm using:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "my identitiy pool id", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1 // Region
    );

    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());

    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(
            "mybucket",     /* The bucket to download from */
            "logo.png",    /* The key for the object to download */
            imageFile        /* The file to download the object to */
    );
```

This code throws the following error:

```
    E/DownloadTask: Failed to download: 8 due to The provided token has expired. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredToken; Request ID: 6BEA65FAFAD54BF4)
```

I've just created the credentials on AWS Cognito, it cannnot expire. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary issue probably. I retried after sometime and it worked.